# ios when I add second app, do I need to add a second app's certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning

I have one ios developer account. And I have distribution app in appstore.

I want to add my second app to appstore.

do I need to add certificate about second app?

(and more information plz)

Comment: Thanks. 
But another problem occurred.
when I submit to appstore my second app, xcode gave to me message

Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets
your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate
you have a valid iOS distribution certificate in the member center, but it is not installed locally. if your siging identity is installed on another mac, you can export a developer profile on that mac and import it on this mac. you cna also revoke your current certificate and request a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about Distribution Certificate, NO, you don't require to generate a new one. However, you'll still require to generate the followings in order to push a new App to App Approval (after approval, to the App Store):

1. App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile (this can be generated by Xcode)
2. APNs Production Certificate (if you use Push Notification) with your new App's App ID

Answer (score 3):

No. You need to create new App ID and Provisioning profile for it and reuse old Distribution certificate